# Xamarin: How to get AdvertisingId on Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need `AdvertisingId` (for AdDeals if you wonder why). I tried this:

```
return Android.Gms.Ads.Identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.GetAdvertisingIdInfo(MainActivity.Instance).Id;
```

but it throws this exception:

> {Java.IO.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out
>   waiting for the service connection --->
>   Java.Util.Concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for the
>   service connection    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in :0    at
>   Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod
>   (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo
>   method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in
>   <7802aa64ad574c33adca332a3fa9706a>:0    at
>   Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass,
>   System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x0000e] in
>   <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0    at
>   Android.Gms.Ads.Identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.GetAdvertisingIdInfo
>   (Android.Content.Context context) [0x00047] in
>   :0 
>         --- End of managed Java.IO.IOException stack trace --- java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out
>   waiting for the service connection    at
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zza(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.start(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown
>   Source) Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out
>   waiting for the service connection    at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.zza.zza(Unknown Source)     ... 3 more }

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `IOException` in this context is a "signaling connection to Google Play Services failed." So, either your emulator/device does not have internet access or the service is down... so in this case I would highly assume it is a connectivity issue on your side...

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for your reply. The device has internet access. Do I need any special permission to access that method?

Comment: Should the app be published on Google Play (I doubt)?

Comment: That call will return an ID even if it has not been published to Play, other than providing a valid Application or Activity context, executing it on a background thread and having an Internet connection (and Internet permission in the manifest of course), there is nothing else you should have to do.